# SetwindowsHookEX not working when application is not run in elevated mode on Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-10, setwindowshookex

I have native dll for setting the windows hook and I am calling it in one of my windows application to set it to a target application. It works perfectly fine when the target application is run in admin(elevated) mode with CallWndProcHook call back triggered.

But when I run my target application in non admin(not elevated) mode then the SetWindowsHookEx is successful but the CallWndProcHook call back does not get triggered.

```
static LRESULT WINAPI CallWndProcHook(int nHookCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::ofstream DEBUG_STRM;
    DEBUG_STRM.open (FILE, std::fstream::app);
    DEBUG_STRM << "\n CallWndProcHook entered";
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nHookCode, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C"  __declspec( dllexport ) int _stdcall Start(long handle)
{
    HWND objectHWND = (HWND)handle;
    DWORD processId;
    DWORD threadId;

    std::ofstream DEBUG_STRM;
    DEBUG_STRM.open (FILE, std::fstream::app);
    DEBUG_STRM << "\n Start hooking";

    threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(objectHWND, &processId);
    HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandle("textlocator.dll");
    g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProcHook, hInst, threadId);

    if(g_hHook == NULL){
        DEBUG_STRM << "\n Hook unsuccessful";
    }else{
        DEBUG_STRM << "\n Hook successful";
    }

    if (g_hHook == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    DEBUG_STRM.close();
}
```

Any help on it ?

Comment: Is objectHWND a window in a elevated process?

Comment: objectHWND is window in non elevated process

Comment: Most every hard to diagnose problem starts with a wrong assumption.  There is one here, you assume the hook doesn't get called but that cannot be distinguished from the process just not being able to open the file.  Or for you being able to find the file back, a very traditional problem caused by not using the full path name.   We can't tell what FILE looks like.